# How can I set up automatic migrations in Entity Framework Core 7 for my ASP.NET Core MVC web app project?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I created an ASP.NET Core 7.0 MVC web app project. I added Entity Framework Core (v7.0.5) package from NuGet Package Manager.

How do I enable the automatic migrations for my code first project?

In the EF 4.3 version we would use the

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AppContext,
ProjectName.Migrations.Configuration>("DBConnectionString"));
```

along with

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
AutomaticMigrationsDataLossAllowed = true;
ContextKey = "ProjectName.AppContext";
```

in the configuration class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for automatic migrations **([Apply migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime))** in ASP.NET Core 7.0.

After these lines in Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();
```

You need to call **context.Database.Migrate()**.

```
using (var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        dbContext.Database.Migrate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio by going to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console.
2. In the Package Manager Console, run the following command to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package:

   ```
   Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
   ```
3. add the following code to the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs file:

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString
   ("DefaultConnection"))
       .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
   ```

   This code configures the DbContext to use SQL Server and enables sensitive data logging.
4. In the Package Manager Console, run the following command to create a new migration:

   ```
   Add-Migration <MigrationName>
   ```

   Replace with a descriptive name for your migration.
5. Finally, run the following command to apply the migration to the database:

   ```
   Update-Database
   ```

   This will apply any pending migrations to the database.

With these steps, your ASP.NET Core Web App (MVC) project is now configured to use automatic migrations with EntityFrameworkCore 7.

Comment: Thank your for you reply, but I still have to run those two commands after I make changes to my model, otherwise the table won't update. Your solution does not automate the process.